# gdb examine and print give different values

Tags: c, debugging, memory, gdb

I am examining the memory in gdb and noticed that `print` and `examine` give 2 different values for the same location.

`(gdb) x/d $ebp-0x1c
0xffffd10c:     126
(gdb) p *0xffffd10c
$1 = 382`

Why is this happening ?

UPD:

As pointed in the answer, that could have happened because I didn't explicitly specify the size to print. I've tried to specify, and I've got similar results:

`(gdb) p/x *0xffffd110
$5:     0x9c9
(gdb) x/x $ebp-0x18
0xffffd110: 0xc9`

Answer (score 2):

The "p" command might implicitly assume a machine word, but "x" remembers the last size you've used with it, which seems to be a character here. To tell it to use a 4-byte word again, you could use "x/wd", for example.